Как преобразовать код в функццию?
есть у меня такой фрагмент кода:
        ces2gTable = pd.DataFrame()
        ces4gTable = pd.DataFrame()
..
            else:
                #print("Это выгрузка из сайта CES")
                cols = [2, 6, 7, 8, 10, 14]
                table = pd.read_excel(locDir+"/"+file, usecols=cols)
                table = table[table["BSS"].isna()]
                #print(table)
                with open("output.log", "a") as outfile:
                    outfile.write("+ File contents received "+file+"\n")
                if "BS_address" in table:
                    ces2gTable = pd.concat([ces2gTable,table])
                elif "RMOD" in table:
                    ces4gTable = pd.concat([ces4gTable,table])
                else: 
                    with open("output.log", "a") as outfile:
                        outfile.write("- Некорректная таблица в файле "+file+"\n")
                with open("output.log", "a") as outfile:
                    outfile.write("+ The necessary 2g 4g data from the file has been loaded into the tables "+file+"\n")
                #print(table)
        print("Таблицы (ces2gTable, ces4gTable) из сайта CES для того, чтобы посмотреть какие данные на сайте не заполнены:")
        print(ces2gTable)
        print(ces4gTable)

Как мне преобразовать такой код в функцию? этот код у меня повторяется везде. только меняется считывание колонок.
Я пробовал это делать таким образом:
ces2gTable = pd.DataFrame()
ces4gTable = pd.DataFrame()
def cesTable(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6):
    cols = [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6]
    table = pd.read_excel(locDir+"/"+file, usecols=cols)
    table = table[table["BSS"].isna()]
    #print(table)
    with open("output.log", "a") as outfile:
        outfile.write("+ File contents received "+file+"\n")
    if "BS_address" in table:
        ces2gTable = pd.concat([ces2gTable,table])
    elif "RMOD" in table:
        ces4gTable = pd.concat([ces4gTable,table])
    else: 
        with open("output.log", "a") as outfile:
            outfile.write("- Некорректная таблица в файле "+file+"\n")
    with open("output.log", "a") as outfile:
        outfile.write("+ The necessary 2g 4g data from the file has been loaded into the tables "+file+"\n")
    #print(table)
    return table
...
            else:
                #print("Это выгрузка из сайта CES")
                cesTable(2, 6, 7, 8, 10, 14)
        print("Таблицы (ces2gTable, ces4gTable) из сайта CES для того, чтобы посмотреть какие данные на сайте не заполнены:")
        print(ces2gTable)
        print(ces4gTable)

Но у меня появляется ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\projects\FillingInDataForTheSite\py.py", line 150, in <module>
    cesTable(2, 6, 7, 8, 10, 14)
  File "P:\projects\FillingInDataForTheSite\py.py", line 17, in cesTable
    ces4gTable = pd.concat([ces4gTable,table])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ces4gTable' referenced before assignment


так передавайте в функцию свои ces4gTable и ces2gTable как параметры.

Ошибка происходит из-за того, что в функциях используются локальные переменные. По умолчанию вы можете получать значения глобальных пременных, но не изменять их. Соответственно, вместо изменения существующей переменной ces4gTable, создаётся новая внутри функции. И прямо во время создания новой локальной переменной происходит обращение к ней. Это приводит к ошибке. Аналогичная проблема будет с ces2gTable.
Добавьте следующую строчку сразу после определения функции:
global ces2gTable, ces4gTable

Стоит заметить, что использование глобальных переменных считается плохой практикой и не рекомендуется, поэтому решайте сами, стоит ли его применять.

Зачем же советовать использовать глобалы?

В данном случае это самый простой способ исправить код.

Конечно, лучше сделать по-другому, но тогда нужно больше подробностей по коду

На всякий случай дополнил ответ.

Как раз таки больше подробностей нужно, чтобы советовать глобалы, а не наоборот

А хорошей практикой считается передавать данные в функцию через аргументы и возвращать return-ом, чтобы меньше запутываться, когда кода много.

Тут уже скорее сам автор кода должен решать, использовать ему глобалы или нет. Это просто один из возможных вариантов решения.
